# Drawing app. How to create undo function in action script 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, function, undo

Can anyone show me how can I make undo function? so this is my current action script. I cant figure how to do it and i see some example in some web site, the action script is to long to under stand. Pls show a simple way that i can make this work.

sorry for bad grammar...

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var pen_mc:MovieClip;
var drawing:Boolean = false;
var penSize:uint = 1;
var penColor:Number = 0x000000;



function init():void{

pen_mc = new MovieClip();
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDrawing);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, isDrawing);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, finishedDrawing);
addChild(pen_mc);

}

init();

function startDrawing(e:MouseEvent):void{

trace("Pen Has started drawing");

drawing = true;
pen_mc.graphics.lineStyle(penSize, penColor);
pen_mc.graphics.moveTo(mouseX, mouseY);


}

function isDrawing(e:MouseEvent):void{
if(drawing){

    pen_mc.graphics.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
}

}


function finishedDrawing(e:MouseEvent):void{

     trace("finished drawing");
     drawing = false;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to store every line that the user draws in a history array. When the user wants to undo, you can then step backwards through the array and remove each line one by one.